# What should I do with FileOutputStream after deleting File

Tags: java, spring-boot, file-io

I am using Spring Boot to develop a method to concatenate many .pfd files into a single one and return its byte array:

```
public byte[] concatDocs() {
    List<Doc> documents = getAllDocs();

    PDFMergerUtility ut = new PDFMergerUtility();

    String nameOfTemporaryFile = "temporaryFile.pdf";

    File file = new File(nameOfTemporaryFile);

    FileOutputStream out = null;

    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(file);

        for (Doc doc : documents) {
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(doc.getFile());
            ut.addSource(is);
        }

        ut.setDestinationStream(out);
        ut.mergeDocuments(null);

        byte[] fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());

        file.delete();

        return fileBytes;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The code itself is working perfectly: It gets the `Doc` List, creates the temporary `File` along with the `FileOutputStream` (from `java.io`), uses the `PDFMergerUtility` to unite the files and generate the byte array and finally deletes the file from the computer. My questions are:

Every code I see on the internet that works with I/O Stream always closes them in the end (with `stream.close()`), but I've never found a good explaination on why they always do this...
Should I close `out` before I `readAllBytes`?
Should I close `out` before or after I delete the File?
As I'm deleting the File, do I even need to close `out`?
What if an Exception is thrown? Should I close `out` on a `finally` clause?
Should I `out.flush()` somewhere?
Should I call `System.gc();`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is similar to yours.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26541513/why-is-it-good-to-close-an-inputstream

Comment: You need to close it *before* deleting the file. Otherwise the deletion may not work. But if you're going to load it all into memory, why not use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead?

Answer (score 0):

From java 7, they introduce try with resource (you can see in oracle document). It can help to reduce closing stream manually.

Answer (score 0):

Closing the resource is always preferable to avoid any leak of data.
In `Java-7` we have the try with resource feature you can use that.
`try-with-resources` – allows us to declare resources to be used in a try block with the assurance that the resources will be closed when after the execution of that block.
You can find more about the same here
 https://mkyong.com/java/try-with-resources-example-in-jdk-7/ or 
 https://www.baeldung.com/java-try-with-resources